# sas loop for each rows

Tags: loops, sas

I have data in following form

```
dataset A   A   B       dataset B   C   D   E   F
            1   7                   3   2   1   9
            2   8                   5   3   4   5
            3   9                   6   5   5   6
            4   10                  2   7   2   11
            5   11                  7   9   14  8
            6   12                  9   5   8   13
```

I'm trying to construct a loop.
I want create following dataset

```
 A  B   C   D   E   F   G
1   7   3   2   1   9   A+B-(C+D-E+F)
1   7   5   3   4   5   A+B-(C+D-E+F)
1   7   6   5   5   6   A+B-(C+D-E+F)
1   7   2   7   2   11  A+B-(C+D-E+F)
1   7   7   9   14  8   A+B-(C+D-E+F)
1   7   9   5   8   13  A+B-(C+D-E+F)
.
.
.
```

Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a Cartesian Product. Can do the below to get desired result!

taking the input dataset names to be a and b

```
proc sql;
create table new as
select a.*, b.*, A+B-(C+D-E+F) as G
from a,b;
quit;
```

Comment: Well it seems like a cartesian product. First row in dataset A is matched with all others in Dataset B if we look at the desired result. And then there are three dots which would generally mean that the pattern is supposed to continue. If that's not the case - could anyone help me see what I missed.

Comment: You are correct. I misread the want part of question -- removed my 1-1 merge answer and comment.